# Html code Not returning decimal values in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have below code in one of our stored procedures.

```
SELECT  
   '<table width=100% style=''FONT-SIZE: 10px; FONT-FAMILY: MS Reference Sans Serif;''><tr><td>' + 
   '</td><Other Wages</td><td al<td align=center>' +
   LTRIM(STR(0.30))+'</td></tr></table>' AS SCHEDSTATS
```

The problem with above code is, it doesn't return the decimal values. the output of the above code came like this,

```
<table width=100% style='FONT-SIZE: 10px; FONT-FAMILY: MS Reference Sans Serif;'>
   <tr>
       <td></td><Other Wages</td>
       <td al<td align=center>0</td></tr></table>
```

(I have given `0.30` decimal value which becomes `0` in output). How can I show decimal value in the above code?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Wow, you have html code generated in sp? :-O

Comment: @oscar. Yes seems to be a very old sp in the application which generate email for the users in the html format

Comment: @tinka.   the html code doesn't returns decimal value. instead of returning 0.30 , it returns 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Syntaxes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms189527.aspx)

```
STR ( float_expression [ , length [ , decimal ] ] )
```

float_expression

```
Is an expression of approximate numeric (float) data type with a decimal point.
```

length

```
Is the total length. This includes decimal point, sign, digits, and spaces. The default is 10.
```

decimal

```
Is the number of places to the right of the decimal point. decimal must be less than or equal to 16. If decimal is more than 16 then the result is truncated to sixteen places to the right of the decimal point.
```

Code

```
SELECT STR(0.30, 3,2);
```

> if you don't want any change you just want `0.30` don't use `STR` use
>   `LTRIM((0.30))`

Answer (score 2):

You got your STR syntax wrong.
The syntax is

**STR( number [, length [, decimal_places ] ] )**

so you need to provide decimal places in the STR to see the decimal value or else it gets rounded-off.

You can find below link helpful:

***http://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/str.php***

Answer (score 2):

It's not an HTML problem. The STR() function returns a rounded integer unless you specify a number of decimals greater than 0.

You must write "STR(0.30, 5, 2)", that means "return a string of maximum 5 digits, with 2 decimals".

The result will be correct.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server 2008R2

```
select LTRIM(STR(0.30))
```

0

```
select LTRIM(STR(0.30,8,2))
```

0.30